# Remove add to cart button for specific product categories in WooCommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

I need to hide the "add to cart" button for products of a defined product category.

I would like the quantity fied still visible because I am using the Yith request a quote plugin which uses quantities for the quote system.

The goal: hide "add to cart" button for a certain product category keeping the quantities fields.

Im looking for a short string of code to place in my `functions.php` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Updated:** *(Added compatibility for WooCommerce Product Add-ons plugin in simple products)*.

Here is the way *(for defined product categories for simple and variable product types)* to:

- *Optionally*, On archives pages: Replace add-to-cart buttons by a linked button to the product.
- On single product pages: Remove add to cart button *(keeping quantities fields)*

The code:

```
// function add back quantities without button (variable product)
function add_back_quantities_variable_products(){
    global $product;

    ?>
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart variations_button">
    <?php

    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity' );

    woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
        'min_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(), $product ),
        'max_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', $product->get_max_purchase_quantity(), $product ),
        'input_value' => isset( $_POST['quantity'] ) ? wc_stock_amount( $_POST['quantity'] ) : $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(),
    ) );

    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_quantity' );
    ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo absint( $product->get_id() ); ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo absint( $product->get_id() ); ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" class="variation_id" value="0" />
    </div>
    <?php
}


// function add back quantities without button (simple product)
function add_back_quantities_simple_products(){
    global $product;

    if ( ! $product->is_purchasable() ) return;

    echo wc_get_stock_html( $product );

    if ( $product->is_in_stock() ) : ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form' ); ?>

        <form class="cart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            <?php
                // For WooCommerce Product add-ons (Update)
                do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button' ); 

                do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity' );

                woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
                    'min_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(), $product ),
                    'max_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', $product->get_max_purchase_quantity(), $product ),
                    'input_value' => isset( $_POST['quantity'] ) ? wc_stock_amount( $_POST['quantity'] ) : $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(),
                ) );

                do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_quantity' );
            ?>
        </form>

    <?php
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form' );
    endif;
}


// Replacing add to cart button and quantities by your custom button in Single product pages
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'conditionally_replacing_template_single_add_to_cart', 1, 0 );
function conditionally_replacing_template_single_add_to_cart() {
    global $product, $post;

    // Set HERE your product categories in the array
    $terms = array( 't-shirts', 'gloves' );

    if( has_term( $terms, 'product_cat' ) ){

        // For variable product types
        if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ){
            // Removing add to cart button and quantities
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );

            // Add back quantities without button
            add_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'add_back_quantities_variable_products', 20 );
        }
        // For simple product types
        else if( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) )
        {
            // Removing add to cart button and quantities
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );

            // Add back quantities without button
            add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'add_back_quantities_simple_products', 30 );
        }
    }
}
```

*And optionally (for archives pages)*:

```
// Replacing the button add to cart by a link to the product in Shop and archives pages
// For variable and simple products
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'replace_loop_add_to_cart_button', 10, 2 );
function replace_loop_add_to_cart_button( $button, $product  ) {
    // Set HERE your product categories in the array
    $terms = array( 't-shirts', 'gloves' );

    // Only for simple products
    if( ! $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) return;

    if( has_term( $terms, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ){
        $button_text = __( "View product", "woocommerce" );
        $button = '<a class="button" href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' . $button_text . '</a>';
    }
    return $button;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested under WooCommerce 3+ and works.

---

**For Product tags** - If you want that to work with product tags, you will replace:

```
if( has_term( $terms, 'product_cat' ) ){
```

by

```
if( has_term( $terms, 'product_tag' ) ){
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't need a link to product button because I don't have add to cart buttons visible on archive pages. customers can only see add to cart within the individual product pages. Can you simplify the code to not include that? THanks!

Comment: Thanks for the Answer and the info. It worked for me and I just removed the  last string because I dont have these buttons visible on shop/archive pages already. I will be sure to post what I have already tried with code in my question so people dont think im just asking for free code. thank you!

Comment: Hey LoicTheAztec. Your code worked flawlessly. I have one more question that I believe will not only help me but others with the same problem. I am trying to use "product add-ons" but this string of code makes product add-ons disappear as well. I have been researching looking over the code and cant figure out why this would cause add-ons to be removed. There must be some relationship between the "add to cart" button and product add-ons. Any further help would be appreciated if you feel so inclined. Thanks

Comment: @LukeBaumann I have answer your new question, and updated the code in here too, to be compatble with WooCommerce Product Add-ons plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It works with tags as well.

Just replace `$categories` with `$tags` and `product_cat` with `product_tag`