# How to add the buy now button to a product with hidden add to cart button?

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have items that are using Woocommerce Product Add-ons. This plugin uses the POST method, however I wanted to keep the Ajax buttons for the other products.

Based on *"[Remove add to cart button for specific product categories in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47614054/remove-add-to-cart-button-for-specific-product-categories-in-woocommerce-3/47617676#47617676)"* answer code  That removes the add-to-cart button **for specific product tags** on single product pages, but problem now is I have no button to show.

The code replace also the ajax add to cart button by a button linked to the product and on single product pages, when hitting RETURN/ENTER key, the product is added to cart, which is exactly what I wanted. However, I want to have a Buy Now or Submit button in place. What should I do?

Comment: I don't want the current add-to-cart button because the default one uses Ajax and the plugin uses Post method. I want to remove the current add-to-cart button (which the code fulfilled) but by doing so of course I no longer have any button on the single product page. Disclaimer: I'm not a coder.

Comment: Also, the code works perfectly for my aim (the ajax add to cart still works on other products) it's just that there's no button.

Comment: What I want to achieve is not for archive pages but for single product pages. If I understand correctly, the last hooked function only replaces the button on archive pages. As I have mentioned in the original question, I wanted this for single product pages, not archive page. Apparently, my current theme uses ajax add-to-cart for Single Product Pages as well. I have no problem with archive pages because my shop pages don't have an ATC button.

Comment: Yes but that is with your theme and not on default WooCommerce behavior as there is no ajax add to cart on single product pages… So you need to ask in your theme 's author support pages. On Stack OverFlow nobody can handle your specific case.

Comment: I have already asked and it's a custom solution I have to pay for. I'm asking because, although I'm not a programmer, I'm a front-end web designer with  knowledge in HTML, CSS and Javascript. I am hopeful that someone can give me direction so I can learn how to do it myself and geek over it. I'd like to learn but if what you're saying is true and nobody can help me here, can you point me to a place where someone can teach me how to do it? I'm not up for the end result, I genuinely want to learn.

Comment: Like I said, I am almost there. I am hoping that someone can help me out. I just need a button there that goes to cart page or checkout.

Comment: The related customizations could be on the Woocommerce templates located under the `woocommerce` folder inside your main theme on subfoders `single-product` `>` `add-to-cart` for `simple.php` and `variable.php` PHP template files… Read [*"Overriding templates via a theme"*](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)…